# how to limit droppable to contain only full draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

So how to limit droppable to contain only full draggable?

Look at this example.. http://jsfiddle.net/jWNkh/1/.. 
Try to drag the draggable to the droppable and you'll see that the droppable accept even if the draggable is only half in.

How to make it not accept if the draggable is only half in? how to make it accept only if the draggable is fully in the droppable?

you can see in jsfiddle but my JS code is

```
$('#drag').draggable({ revert: "invalid"});
$('#drop').droppable();​
```

Comment: The `droppable` docs shows how.

Answer (score 7):

Use `tolerance: "fit"`

```
$('#drop').droppable({ tolerance: "fit" });​
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jWNkh/2/)

You can find [documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept)

Comment: It's not work always..look at this picture http://postimage.org/image/9bauk2xp1/ you can test it here http://jsfiddle.net/jWNkh/7/

Comment: It's getting confused by additional margin values. Here is an updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/jWNkh/8/